# How do you add the contents of multiple lists into ListView items and subitems?

Tags: c#, list, listview, items

I have a couple of lists that contain the name of events and the type of event, whether a team or individual event. The name of each event and type of event are separated by semicolons.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.eventName = "Chess;Football;Paintball;Swimming";
Properties.Settings.Default.eventName = "indiv;team;team;indiv";
List<string> eventName = Properties.Settings.Default.eventName.Split(';').ToList();
List<string> eventType = Properties.Settings.Default.eventType.Split(';').ToList();
```

I want these in the form of a list so I can easily add in more events later. How do you add these into a ListView in the following configuration, with event names as items and event types as subitems?

```
 _________________________
| Name       | Type       | <--- column names
|____________|____________|
| Chess      | Individual |
|____________|____________|
| Football   | Team       |
|____________|____________|
| Paintball  | Team       |
|____________|____________|
| Swimming   | Individual |
|____________|____________|
```

What I have so far. This just adds the items, not sure what to do about adding the subitems as it says "ListView does not contain a definition for SubItems".

```
foreach (string eventNameItem in eventName)
{
    lvEvents.Items.Add(eventNameItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code. I think it works.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.eventName = "Chess;Football;Paintball;Swimming";
Properties.Settings.Default.eventType = "indiv;team;team;indiv";
List<string> eventName = Properties.Settings.Default.eventName.Split(';').ToList();
List<string> eventType = Properties.Settings.Default.eventType.Split(';').ToList();

for(int i=0;i< eventName.Count; i++)
{
    string[] row = { eventName[i], eventType[i] };
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

or use

```
//Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
listView1.Columns.Add("eventName", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("eventType", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

for (int i = 0; i < eventName.Count; i++)
{
    string[] row = { eventName[i], eventType[i] };
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
 }
```